# RegexKitLite not matching square brackets

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, regexkitlite

I'm trying to match usernames from a file. It's kind of like this:

username=asd123 password123

and so on.

I'm using the regular expression:

```
username=(.*) password
```

To get the username. But it doesn't match if the username would be say and[ers] or similar. It won't match the brackets. Any solution for this?

Comment: How can I escape them if I don't know they're coming? The usernames are entered by the users so I don't know what they are beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the regular expression:

`username=([a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]+) password`

Or something similar. Notes regarding this:

- Escaping the brackets ensures you get a literal bracket.
- The `a-zA-Z0-9` spans match alphanumeric characters (as per your example, which was alphanumerc). So this would match any alphanumeric character or brackets.
- The `+` modifier ensures that you match *at least one character*. The `*` ([Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)) will allow *zero* repetitions, meaning you would accept an empty string as a valid username.
- I don't know if RegexKitLite allows POSIX classes. If it does, you could use `[:alnum:]` in place of `a-zA-Z0-9`. The one I gave above should work if it doesn't, though.

Alternatively, I would disallow brackets in usernames. They're not really needed, IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. And it's not up to me to disallow brackets, these usernames have existed for years and brackets have always been allowed, unfortunately :(

Comment: You may also want to post a little more code, if possible. It does seem unusual that the `(.*)` expression isn't matching here, so I would definitely check how you are parsing the file and passing the string into the regex. It could be an issue of the string itself being malformed when you encounter a bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Your Regular Expression is correct. Instead, you may try this one:

```
username=([][[:alpha:]]*) password
```

**[**`][[:alpha:]`**]** means `]` and `[` and `[:alpha:]` are contained within the brackets.

Comment: No.. [] is an empty character class.

Comment: This approach is not a mistake... `]` after `[` is known as a regular character in my example... So `[]` is not interpreted as `[]` and it is not an empty character class in my regular expression. you can read more info at: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/Regular_Expression_Syntaxes